Ki Savo: Idols of Wood and Stone
Devarim 28:64 says:

וֶהֱפִֽיצְךָ֤ יְהֹוָה֙ בְּכׇל־הָ֣עַמִּ֔ים מִקְצֵ֥ה הָאָ֖רֶץ
וְעַד־קְצֵ֣ה הָאָ֑רֶץ וְעָבַ֨דְתָּ שָּׁ֜ם אֱלֹהִ֣ים אֲחֵרִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֧ר
לֹא־יָדַ֛עְתָּ אַתָּ֥ה וַאֲבֹתֶ֖יךָ עֵ֥ץ וָאָֽבֶן׃
יהוה will scatter you among all the peoples from one end of the earth to the other, and
there you shall serve other gods, wood and stone, whom neither you nor
your ancestors have experienced

Of course, the galus part came true literally, but I am wondering about the אֱלֹהִ֣ים אֲחֵרִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֧ר לֹא־יָדַ֛עְתָּ אַתָּ֥ה וַאֲבֹתֶ֖יךָ עֵ֥ץ וָאָֽבֶן.
B’zmanenu, there are still certain groups who perform avodah zara for wooden idols, but they are not at all dominant outside of India l’choira.
Rashi writes:

ועבדתם שם אלהים אחרים. כְּתַרְגּוּמוֹ — לֹא עֲבוֹדַת אֱלֹהוּת מַמָּשׁ
אֶלָּא מַעֲלִים מַס וְגֻלְגֹּלִיּוֹת לְכוּמְרֵי עֲ"זָ: ועבדתם שם אלהים
אחרים
AND YE WILL SERVE THERE OTHER GODS — Understand this as the
Targum does: (ye will serve the peoples that worship idols); not
actually that they shall serve idols, but they will have to pay
tribute and poll-taxes to the priests of the idols.

This makes sense in Rashi’s France, when his government was explicitly Christian, but how do we understand this for our generation?
Are our “idols” money and values contrary to Torah? Are the “priests” politicians and bureaucrats?
Edit: this question is distinct from another question regarding the idea of contemporary nochri idolatry in that it is with reference to this particular pasuk.

The Satmar Rav (Divrei Yoel Al HaMoadim, Shekalim, Zachor, Purim, p. 54-55 ff.) explains that nowadays, we have different kind of avodah zarah than there was back in the days. He says:

כי הנה כן אנו רואים היום שמלבישים תמיד איזה צורה אחרת לעבודה זרה ועל ידי זה כבר נמשכים אחריה שאומרים שאינו כמו אותו עד עכשיו אלא שהוא באופן אחר
For indeed, we see today that idolatry is constantly being disguised in new forms, and through this disguise, people are led astray after it. They claim that it is not the same as the idolatry of the past but something different


וזאת ועוד נוסף כי אכן לאמיתו של דבר הרי המתבונן מבחין שבאמת נשאר הכל ממש כאותו העבודה זרה שהיתה מלפנים אלא שיש בכוחו של היצר הרע לטכס עצה ולמצוא תמיד איזה לבוש שונה באופן אחר שיוכל להלביש בזה את העבודה זרה שתהיה נראית שהיא אחרת
Moreover, upon closer reflection, one can discern that in reality, nothing has changed—it remains exactly the same idolatry as it was before. The only difference is that the evil inclination has the ability to devise new strategies and continuously find different ways to cloak idolatry in various forms

So, according to the opinion of the Satmar Rav, avodah zarah changes. De avodah zarah of the time of pharao is not the same as we have now, but the foundational ideas are the same.
He says:

ומעתה נאמר שכל זה רמוז באומרו לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים דהנה אמרו ז"ל במכילתא מכילתא ס' בחודש פ"ס ומובא ברש"י שמוח כ' ג' לבאר אומרו לא יהיה וגו' על פני כל זמן שאני קיים שלא תאמר שלא נצטוו על ע"ז אלא אותו הדור ע"כ ולדרכינו הכוונה שלא תאמר שלא נצטוו אלא על אותו הלבוש והדמות שהיתה נראית העבודה זרה שבאותו הדור ולכן אמר אלהים אחרים היינו שנצטוו גם אפילו אם ישתנו דמותי וצורות הע"ז שיהיו נראין באופן אחר מכפי שהיו אז וכדבר האמור שהצורות והלבושים שלהם משתנים תמיד וזהו כוונת אומרו שאלו נפרש להם כל שם ע"ז לא היה מספיק כל העורות שבעולם דהנה גם אצל פרעה לא היו רק אותם הע"ז שהיו אז בימיו אבל לא היה יודע מה שיהיה אחריו וכל אופני שמות העבודה זרה שיש בימינו אלה לא היה לו בספרו אמנם כוונת המכילתא הוא על כל אופני העבודה זרה שיתחדשו בהמשך כל הדורות ועל כך אמרו שאכן אם ירצו לכתוב כולם מה שהיו בהמשך הזמנים ועד לימינו אלה בעיקבתא דמשיחא שתמיד משתנים בדמותם ולבושיהם השונים הרי ודאי שלא היה מספיק כל העורות שבעולם כי אין להם שיעור
As we mentioned earlier, the forms and appearances of idolatry are
constantly changing. This is what the verse means when it says that if
we were to specify the name of every idol, all the hides in the world
would not suffice. Just as in the time of Pharaoh, only the idols of
his time were known, but he had no knowledge of the idols that would
come after him, nor did his book contain the names of all the forms of
idolatry that exist in our time. The intention of the Mechilta is to
encompass all forms of idolatry that will arise throughout the
generations. And they said that if one were to attempt to write down
all the forms of idolatry that have existed from then until today, in
the footsteps of the Messiah, where idolatry constantly changes its
form and appearance, all the hides in the world would not suffice, for
there is no limit to them


One can use the quoted passage to include atheism. In colleges professors like to tell a story that polytheists worship many gods, monotheists worship one god, and then there are progressive atheists who do not worship anyone. As an answer, one can use the comment of R. Eliyahu Mizrachi on Rashi Bereshis 18:4, which defines atheism as avoda zara:

ורחצו רגליכם כסבור שהם ערביים כו'. במציעא פרק השוכר את הפועלים ולאו מרחיצה קא מפיק לה דאם כן לבן שלא היה מקפיד למה נתן להם מים לרחוץ וכן לוט שלא היה מקפיד שהרי הקדי' לינה לרחיצה למה נתן להם לרחוץ אלא עכ"ל דרחיצה אורחא דמילתא היא לכל הולכי דרכים והא דדרז"ל אינו אלא מדהקדים רחיצה לביאה שלא כדרך המנהג שמנהג העולם להכניסם תחלה ואחר כך לרחוץ והיינו דמסיים אבל לוט שלא הקפיד הקדים לינה לרחיצה כלומר כפי דרך המנהג לא כאברהם דאם לא כן מה טעם להזכיר כאן את לוט ונראה לי דאבק רגליהם לאו דוקא אלא לכל אבק הם משתחוים והא דנקט אבק רגליהם משום דאורחייהו דהולכי דרכים להמצא האבק ברגליהם והא דלא הקפיד בהם על שהיו עובדי כוכבים להכניסם בביתו הוא משו' דאין מקפידין על העובדי' אלא על הנעבדי' שהם עבודת כוכבים עצמם ומפני שכל הלומדים תמהי' על זה היאך אפשר להיות שישתחוה שום אדם לאבק שעל רגליו שהוא הפחות שבנמצאות נראה לי לתת טעם על זה שמפני שהקדמוני' מהפלוסופים היו מאמינים שכל הנמצאות כלם מורכבים מהעצמים הפרדיים שהם האבק ושבחבורם יתהוו כל הנמצאים ובהפרדם יפסדו ושאין מנהיג זולתם רק הם עצמם האלוהו' כמו כת אפיקורוס וסיעתו והאבק נמצא תמיד ברגלי הולכי דרכים הוכרח אברהם אבינו ע"ה לתת להם מים לרחוץ טרם הכנסם בביתו כדי שלא יכנסו בביתו עם האבק שהיו משתחוים לו לשום אלהות לא שהיו משתחוים לאבק שברגליהם ממש:
And wash your feet as you think they are Arabs, etc. The incident is noted in Bava Metziya 86b, perek haSocher es Poalim. And if he did not perform the wash, in the case of Lavan, who was not particular, why did he gave (Eliezer) water to wash (feet) (Bereshis 24:32)? And also Lot, who was not careful, because he offered spending night before washing (feet), why did he offer them to wash (Bereshis 19:2)? Rather, washing was a common custom for all wayfarers. But from the drasha of RZ"L in Bava Metziya 86b it is not so, because Abraham preceded washing (feet) to coming into (the tent) contrary to custom entering the tent and then washing (as Lot did).
It seems to me that the verse is not speaking simply (לאו דוקא) of the dust of the (travelers) feet. Rather, to all kinds of "dust" (i.e. materiality) the bow. And here it chose to speak of the dust of their feet because it is the way of travelers to have dust on their feet. Thus [Lot] was not particular about it when bringing [guests] into the house because he only focused on those who bow to stars themselves. Because anyone who learns wonders how is it possible for a human to bow to dust on one's feet, which is less than material amount? I would like to give reason to it. The ancient philosophers, such as the sect of Epicurus and his helpers, believed that all things that exist are composed of the individual particles that are the dust; and that by joining them one can bring to existence all things; and by separating them one can destroy all things; and that there is no force other than them, only these particles are god himself. Since the dust is always at the feet of wayfarers, Abraham our father was forced to give them water to bathe before entering his tent so that they would not enter his house with the dust that they would bow down as deification of materiality, not that they bowed down to the dust itself on their very feet:

The teachings of Epicurus are pretty much the foundation of the modern atheism. R. Mizrachi states that one cannot view these teachings other than avoda zara.
